# Why is lld saying unknown file type?

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, lld

Could anyone help me on why ld.lld is telling me:

```
clang -ffreestanding -mno-red-zone -m32 -c kernel/main.cpp -o kernel.o
ld.lld -m elf_i386 -T kernel/linker.ld -o kernel.bin kernel.o
ld.lld: error: kernel.o: unknown file type
make: *** [Makefile:13: kernel.bin] Error 1
```

I'm trying to compile kernel/main.cpp, link it with kernel/linker.ld, and then produce a .bin of the kernel, but this error I've been trying to debug for an hour is keeping me from doing that

I've tried google, couldn't find anything

This is my main.cpp file

```
extern "C" void kernelMain() {
    const char* hello = "Hello world!";
    char* vga = (char*)0xb8000;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        vga[i*2] = hello[i];
        vga[i*2+1] = 0x0F;
    }
}

extern "C" void _start() {
    kernelMain();
    while(1) {}
}
```

My linker.ld file:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x1000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

And then my makefile:

```
NASM=nasm
QEMU=qemu-system-x86_64
CC=clang
LD=ld.lld

all: boot.bin kernel.bin

boot.bin: boot/boot.asm
    $(NASM) -f bin -o $@ $<

kernel.bin: kernel/main.cpp kernel/linker.ld
    $(CC) -ffreestanding -mno-red-zone -m32 -c $< -o kernel.o
    $(LD) -T kernel/linker.ld -o $@ kernel.o

run: boot.bin kernel.bin
    $(QEMU) -drive format=raw,file=$<

clean:
    rm -f boot.bin kernel.bin kernel.o
```

Any help is appreaciated

Comment: `file kernel.o` might help to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Resolved, I just used linux with ld and it worked